# How to get logged in user id from browser for internal web application?

Tags: angular, windows, authentication

So I am building web app in angular for team member to track their task. They are logged in to the computer using their network id. how do I capture that in my form ? I don't want to create separate login page.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, [SSO](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/09/23/what-is-and-how-does-single-sign-on-work/) is the way you can achieve your requirement.

Single Sign-On (SSO) is an authentication process that allows a user to access multiple applications with one set of login credentials. SSO is a common procedure in enterprises, where a client accesses multiple resources connected to a local area network (LAN).

You can read more [here](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/09/23/what-is-and-how-does-single-sign-on-work/)

Comment: That I understand, But can I not get user who is logged in to the machine from browser ? I am looking for Angular code.